# Is there a setting on Raspberry Pi 3 to remember the PSK?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, noobs

I am a new Raspberry Pi 3 user.  The system was exceptionally straight forward to initialize, including initial connection to WiFi and getting access to internet.  However, when the connection drops occasionally, and I click the connection icon to re-initialize, the system requires I re-enter the PSK each time.

Is there a setting on this system (using NOOBS OS distribution) to remember the PSK when attempting to re-connect to WiFi?

I did browse the Raspberry -> Preferences -> Raspberry Pi Configuration pages, but with no success at finding anything on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fairly clear, and easy to follow answer to my question *[here](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/raspberry-pi-3-how-to-configure-wi-fi-and-bluetooth/03fcd2a252914350938d8c5471cf3b63)*.

Essentially, get the values for for ESSID using the command: `iwlist wlan0 scan` in a shell. Then, using the information there, verify or edit the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file to contain the following:

```
network={
    ssid="The_ESSID_from_earlier"
    psk="Your_wifi_password"
}
```

This is just a summary. I suggest reading the page link above to get full details.